# Cesaro convergence implies weak convergence of a subsequence

Tags: hilbert-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Suppose a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in the Cesaro sense (i.e., $\frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n)\rightarrow x$) in a separable Hilbert space $H$. How to prove that some subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges weakly to $x$?

Comment: Reminds me of Banach-Saks theorem, which goes the other way.

Comment: Indeed, looks like the exercise might've been intended the other way. For the record: the proof of Banach-Saks can be found in http://books.google.com/books?id=jlQnThDV41UC&pg=PA80&dq=banach+saks&sig=yRtjLNe_LXX5CjVjHazYwRmYYzk#v=onepage&q=banach%20saks&f=false

Comment: Whatever the corrected question is supposed to be, it almost certainly is not research level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we take $x_n = (-1)^n x$ then $x_n$ converges to $0$ in Cesaro sence. But no subsequence of $x_n$ converges weakly to $0$. $x_n$ is also a bounded sequence.
Hence your statements seems wrong.

Comment: Thanks. It was an exercise that I couldn't solve, so I assumed it should hold.

Comment: @Kestutis Cesnavicius: A good habit to be in is that if you cannot prove a statement, try to break it.  Either you succeed in falsifying the statement, or you gain more understanding of why the statement should be true.

Comment: Kestutis, may be it was asked (or they wanted to ask) to prove that some subsequence weakly converges, but not necessary to $x$? Which is not very deep, too, but it is true at least.